# Building and running binaries using Cmake (on Linux) linking problem

Tags: cmake

I have built a server binary using cmake (and also make) for arm and x86 targets. I am able to run my server on arm using correct linking paths for RPATH, for example populating CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH. However when I try to run my x86 server it complains about not being able to find my databases. Would I be right in saying that CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH is used for libraries only and not to find files or databases. Is there another cmake variable that is used to find files or databases at run time or by correctly populating CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH it should find files and databases as-well as libraries.

Thanks Paul.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH only deals with finding shared libraries.  Specifically, setting the RPATH just gives the dynamic linker a list of directories to search for shared libraries.

If you want to find a file or database at runtime from within your application, you have to get the paths into your application some other way.  This could be via a config file or hardcoded constants that are different for each platform.